# Why isn't jquery working in Rails 3.1?

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I go to http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js my code (which works fine in 3.0) exists, because I've referenced it fine in the new application.js assets pipeline file:

```
$(document).ready
(function(){
    $('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'  
});
});
```

But it's not being called. Jquery is present, too, and my gemfile got upgraded ok. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was that I had a number of bits of code within a .js file I'd called various.js, and not all of them were wrapped in `$(document).ready... });` Once I added that to each separate bit of code it worked fine. Also, I have to restart the server each time I make a change to the .js file - just touching it doesn't work for me. I found a simple Hello World alert really useful in debugging this (just in case anyone out there is as new to jquery as me!):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Hello world!")
});
```